# A Responsive Photo-wall Gallery with Swipe Functionality

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, gallery, photo

I'm looking to build a javascript/jquery gallery that meets the criteria below, and would love to know if there are any existing gallery modules that have all/most of these features:

**1.** Photo wall with zoom (single view) functionality. eg. http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingPanelPhotowallGallery/

**2.** Responsive, so that the photo wall images tile properly for desktop & mobile devices, and reshuffle if the user resizes their browser.  eg. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

**3.** (optional but desirable). If a user is on a mobile device, allow them to swipe through single-view images.

**In a nutshell.**  A user will go to the thumbnail wall, select an image, and can then either swipe through more enlarged photos, or switch back to the wall.

**The photos will be sourced from a folder on the server.**  Moderators are simply camera girls, who will upload images from their digital cameras to this folder via ftp - They wont resize / optimise the images, so it would be great if this could happen in the process somewhere too.

We are hosting on a PHP / Linux environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery Mason: http://masonry.desandro.com/

It can be used as a responsive wall.

What your asking for is not called 'zoom' (that is another effect), you seem to what what is called a lightbox. There are a lot of these, here is a comparison, http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/

To re-size images your going to have to write some php to make use of image GD or imagemagick, here is a tutorial,  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/ or possibly a script, http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/ (or timthumb.php).

For serving them your going to have to write some php with your javascript.

There is no all in one solution for what you asking for, you're going to have to write it or hire someone to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you have to create a plugin or write you own jquery functions for getting all customized features.(that will be very good in sense of performance and maintenance)

1. for zooming functionality you can use some of the modal windows with ajax call or you can create.
2. to achieve this you have to write good css so that your photo aligned according to screen.reshuffle will be handled if you write good css.
3. yes you can achieve this by detecting the browser navigator and changing the css and javascript accordingly.
4. For pre processing images(re sizing,dynamically generating thumbanails) you can opt for php backend solutions.
5. And no worries you can handle images from folder via Ajax and show them as they requires.